# Change the following MDX query into MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, cursor, pentaho, pentaho-cde, mysql-function

In pentaho,I used the below is the MDX Query for dropdown ,

```
WITH
      MEMBER [Measures].[Years UniqueName]  AS  
      [Time].currentmember.UniqueName
SET  YEAR  AS  UNION( [Time].[All Years] , [Time].[Years].Members )
SELECT
       [Measures].[Years UniqueName]  ON COLUMNS,
       YEAR   ON ROWS
FROM [SteelWheelsSales];
```

And I got the [image: screenshot]

Here ,when i clicked on "All Years" I got all the year details(eg:2003,2004 etc.).

Now, I need to use MySQL for the dropdown and want to get the field "All years" in it. When I click on it, all details need to display.

Can anybody help me to change the above MDX query into MySQL..

Comment: It would be great help if anybody come up with the answer

Comment: what is the result of this query. select * from SteelWheelsSales limit 10;

Comment: got the above dropdown